# How to replace between two marks with the content of a python variable

Tags: replace, vimscript-python

I'm writing a plugin to convert between word cases, and I would like to apply my filter between two marks.

The conversion part is done with python, but I don't know how can I replace the text between two marks ?

Note, to get the text from two marks, I use this function :

```
def getRange(start_marker, end_marker):
    buf = vim.current.buffer
    (lnum1, col1) = buf.mark(start_marker)
    (lnum2, col2) = buf.mark(end_marker)
    lines = vim.eval(f'getline({lnum1}, {lnum2})')
    if len(lines) == 1:
        lines[0] = lines[0][col1:col2 + 1]
    else:
        lines[0] = lines[0][col1:]
        lines[-1] = lines[-1][:col2 + 1]
    return "\n".join(lines)
```

(found on SO)

Comment: Can we see the relevant part of your code?

Comment: isn't the question not clear enough ?

Answer (score 1):

I can see two options:

1. The "Vim" approach: linewise commands. Write a command that can filter a single line, then use `:'a,'b command…` to apply it to each line in the range. For example, `:'a,'b!my-filter-script`. If using user commands, do `:command -range MyFilter …` and use `<line1>,<line2>` in the command expansion when you need the range.
2. The "Visual" approach: grab the text between the marks (*e.g.*, with visual mode and `` `a `` instead of `'a`); then, operate on it and replace the text. For example, you might do something like

```
… save register @z with getreginfo()
try
  normal! `av`b"zy
  … operate on @z
  normal! `av`b"zp
finally
  … restore register @z with setreginfo()
endtry
```

Comment: Note that the latter is effectively mark-specific, while the former accepts an arbitrary range. But the latter can operate on parts of lines while the fomer cannot. (The latter can be adjusted to work with an arbitrary visual selection, though.)